# Is it common practice to click on a logo to go the home screen?

Tags: menu, logos

I'm designing a website and am creating the wireframes first. I need the website to be as clear and simple as possible. I have 7 menu options in the main menu, one of them being a 'home' button. But I'm wondering if I can leave out the home button because clicking on the logo takes you to the home screen anyway. This would simplify my main menu even more (seeing as I have some spacing issues).

I'm just wondering if this is common practice and if users know by default that clicking a logo takes them to the home screen. After reading a bit I tend to think it isn't, but I'd like to have other opinions as well.

Comment: There are several [very similar questions](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=logo+home+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 1):

The fact is it really depends on your users.  I think it's become more and more common that users know to do that but that is generalizing a bit.  Best thing to is user test it.  From a purely usability stand point, the ideal case is definitely to include it however there's often design and space considerations.  I would look to see if you can trim down on your nav items before removing the home button if you must.

Other considerations I have when including or not including the home button is to ask the following questions:

1. Is there a need for the user to go back to the homepage often during a session? 
   Sometimes the home page is just an intro to the site and rarely does the user go back in one session. This means even if they don't figure out that the logo brings them back to home, they can probably use the back button or some other means to figure out how to get back there.
2. Is it expected that the user will land on your home page?
   If this is an existing site you can check analytics.  Otherwise it'll be a bit of a guess.  Not all sites have their home page as a "front door".  Blogs for example will get a lot of entries from an article page.  The ability to navigate back to the home page in that case is very important.